# AdView Banner inside Tabbed Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, adbannerview

I'm trying to show banner ad inside Linear Layout activity that has tabs(which are fragments).

But whatever I try, the ad banner doesn't show up.
Here is my code:

XML:

activity_hometopnav.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_hometabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.vossenthemes.swappuser.activities.homepages.HomeTopNavActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbarlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccentLight"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/colorAccentLight"
        />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_banner_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp">

        <ProgressBar
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_color"
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-3dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:max="100"
            android:progress="20"/>

    </FrameLayout>
```

JAVA:

HomeTopNavActivity.java

```
 MobileAds.initialize(this, getString(R.string.admob_banner_id));
 bannerAd = findViewById(R.id.adView2);
 bannerAd.loadAd(adRequest);
```

I'm trying to show banner ad inside Linear Layout activity that has tabs(which are fragments).

But whatever I try, the ad banner doesn't show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Viewpager's height is match_parent. So there is no room for adview. You can use android:layout_weight for this problem. For example:

```
  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

  <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="64dp"       <--- You can change height
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_banner_id">
  </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Comment: Thank you sir, that solved my problem! However there is white space that fills empty area on the left and right side of the banner. Care to know why does that happen?

Comment: Your welcome! You can change ad size with this attribute: "ads:adSize" (I use SMART_BANNER the most.). You can find more detail in here: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner#banner_sizes

Comment: Great. Thanks Mete!